# Most of Kinetic.JS SVG images doesn't appear in Safari

Tags: ios, html, svg, safari, kineticjs

All i trying to do is draw some of svg images on canvas using Kinetic.js image. So, i exported many of them from Adobe Illustrator to svg and everything was render nice in every browser i test it before i open iPad iOS 7.1 Safari and see that he draw only 2 images from 50! The strange thing to say is that when i open svg directly in Safari they work well, but if i trying to draw them on canvas only some of them would appear.

Here is example with two images - one of them work fine in Safari when another doesn't even appear:

http://jsbin.com/fitefiya/4/edit

```
var imgObj = new Image();

imgObj.onload = function(){
    var testPicture = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: imgObj.width,
        height: imgObj.height,
        image: imgObj
    });

    testLayer.add(testPicture);
    testLayer.draw();

    console.log('image was loaded');
};
//this don't work only on iPad Safari, but works well in any other browser
imgObj.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/42i35ug37uiwg6d/titleBooks.svg';

//this svg work well even on Safari
//imgObj.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1q7cduvxdktvcbg/titleStartButton.svg';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in mobile Safari resource size limits, that i was thinking should not affect vector images. But it does.

Here is some more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html